# Run CountVectorizer on single column Series from two-column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, countvectorizer

**How does one convert a single column from a pandas dataframe with multiple columns into a Series for CountVectorizer?**

I have a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns x 9372 records (rows):

- The first column is called `twodig` and is an integer
- The second column is called `descrp` and is a varchar
- [image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqb4i.jpg)

After removing stopwords and special characters, I want to use CountVectorizer on `descrp` column only, but still keep `twodig`.

```
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
bowmatrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
```

However running CountVectorizer requires the dataframe to be converted into a pandas series, which is then run with CountVectorizer.

```
corpus = pd.Series(df)
```

But when I run the script, the resulting error: **Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 9372**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that column only from you DataFrame like this: `df["descrp"]` so your code will be:

```py
import pandas

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

bowmatrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["descrp"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but is less than optimal to work with after that.

```py
import pandas 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer() 
df["bowmatrix"] = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["descrp"])
```

Comment: @Enduringness If it's the awser you was looking for, could you mark it as validate by clicking on the check button under the up/down vote one. Otherwise, comment here.